# Backslash before single quote breaks syntax highlighting (the quote is not escaped, but gets highlighted as if it is) in SEDE query

Tags: bug, data-explorer, syntax-highlighting

I was trying to write a query to find posts with `<%break%>` or `<%%>`, and realised that `%` works as a glob. Someone [suggested](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3877?m=54871743#54871743) using `ESCAPE '\'` to search for literal `%`, and that worked and [the query](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/1259742/posts-with-broken-breaks) gave the expected output, but the syntax highlighting made it look as if it wouldn't:

[image: bad syntax highlighting]

I'm not sure if this is specific to `ESCAPE` clauses? I'm sorry I'm describing it so unclearly, but it does seem like a bug to me.

Comment: There is a non hopeful comment [in the code](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/blob/master/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Scripts/codemirror/sql.js#L107) but if I find some time I'll see if that is related to the bug you reported here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have pushed a fix for the [sql.js](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/blob/master/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Scripts/codemirror/sql.js#L107) file that I identified earlier.

The pull request can found [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/104). The `tokenString` function now correctly parses T-SQL strings and no longer assumes a `\` is an escape character. It does handle the escaping of a quote in a T-SQL string as well as the handling of strings that start and end with double quotes.

The PR needs to be merged and deployed by SE staff and that can take 6 to 8 weeks.